# System of equations has a solution

Tags: functions

How can I  prove that:

$$\begin{cases}\left|xy\right|-x=0 \\ \\ 2y^2-1=\sin(x+y)\end{cases}$$

has a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly the first equation is satisfied if $x=0$. Then it's enough to show that
$$2y^2-1=\sin(y)$$
has a solution $y$. But this is clearly true since if $f(y)=2y^2-1-\sin(y)$, we have $f(0)=-1<0$ while $f(1)=1-\sin(1)>0$.

Comment: +1. Perhaps an easier way to see that $2y^2-1=\sin y$ has a solution is to sketch $2x^2-1$ and $\sin x$.

Comment: Wow. That was easy. I was thinking more about continuity in sense of Heine's definition and later on somehow use any fixed point theorem, but it's much better.

Comment: It wouldn't be that easy if the first equation didn't have an obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try $x = \frac{\pi}{2}-1, y = 1$.